# How to access lib folder modules of ear file from a different deployment on same WildFly server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I have an ear (App.ear) and a war (Web.war) file deployed in the same WildFly. The App.ear contains AppEJB.jar as a module and Util.jar in lib folder of the same. I need the Web.war to be able to see the Util.jar and AppEJB.jar of App.ear. For the modules AppEJB.jar to be seen from Web.war I've put jboss-deployment-structure.xml in the META-INF folder of the Web.war as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.App.ear.AppEJB.jar" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

The question is how do I access the Util.jar from Web.war?

Comment: I don't know about WildFly, but the deployment approach you're attempting isn't a good idea since you would be breaking the ear/war self containment of what it needs to run.  Possible alternatives:  1) include the AppEJB/Util jars in the war to allow the ear and war to be deployed independently; 2) include the war within the ear to make the jars visible to the war; 3) Assuming it's supported, add the jars to a shared WildFly lib which would make the jars visible to all deployed ears/wars.

Comment: @AndrewS I do agree that my approach is not a good one but I've some constraints that forces me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need dependency for Util.jar in your Web.war's pom.xml

Comment: Though I'm not using maven I cannot put Util.jar in Web.war file.